# How do I read the output of a batch file into a string in C++

Tags: c++, batch-file

I'm trying to make a small program that will create a Batch file, do something in it and then return a string from it, and after it delete the Batch.

I would like to store the output of the batch file in the variable `line`.

I tried using `getline()` but I think it work with .txt files only. I can be wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ofstream batch;
    string line;

    batch.open("temp.bat", ios::out);
    batch <<"@echo OFF\nwmic os get caption /value\nwmic path win32_videocontroller get description /value\npause\nexit";
    batch.close();

    system("temp.bat");
    remove("temp.bat");
};
```

In my code I simply using `system` with my Batch file. I'd like to use `cout<<line`.

I expect string called `line` would be equal to the output of the Batch file.

Comment: By the way, I'm using main int arguments for future use.

Comment: "I expect string called `line` would be equal to everything inside the Batch file" - I don't understand what that would be the case, given that this variable isn't used anywhere in your code...

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the value. That is, change `ofstream batch; ... batch.open("temp.bat", ios::out);` to `ofstream batch("temp.bat");` (the `ios::out` is redundant; `ofstream` is an output file. Also, if you put this code in a function (for example, "create_batch_file(const char*name)` then you don't have to call `close()` on the stream; the destructor will do that for you.

Comment: Side note: Prefer `<cstdlib` over `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm getting an error using `#include <cstdlib>` as "no such file or directory".

Comment: @EadwineYoun That's odd [cstdlib](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) is a standard C++ header. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using Dev-C++ version 5.11 and Compiler TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release (the default one).

Comment: @ForceBru I didn't use `line` string because I don't know how to convert everything from batch file to this variable. This is why I'm asking you people.

Comment: `wmic.exe` is a standard Windows executable file, so I'm not sure why you need to write, run and delete a [tag:batch-file] for this task. Can you not simply run `"wmic.exe"` twice, each with your required arguments.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to run the batch file and capture the text output and save it into `line`?

Comment: @DaveRager yes, I just need to store what batch file returns in `line`.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to redirect the output to a file and then read that file.

Comment: @Phil1970 could you please tell me how to implement it? I think I didn't get it.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `wmic /?` paying particular attention to the `/output` and `/append` options.

Comment: Something like `command > log_file.txt`. Then you read the file. You might also need to convert the encoding.

Comment: @Compo I don't understand how this can help me.

Comment: I found a way simplier: I could create a new BAT that will do stuff like this: `temp.bat > log.txt` into new text file and C++ console will read it and turn into a string... I guess?

Comment: @EadwineYoun, did you read the `wmic` usage information? It seems very clear to me, and will also work directly instead of writing a [tag:batch-file], _as mentioned in my previous comment_.

Comment: @Compo Well I did, but I have no idea what all this mean. I'm very new at BATCH and don't understand some stuff.

Comment: You might Investigate  'popen'.  When 'input' mode, all output of what-popen-runs is streamed  back to the thread that invoked popen (through a pipe).  There are C++ examples on SO.

Comment: @EadwineYoun A C++ application can use directly the Windows classes to get the information you need in your application. There is absolutely no need to run `wmic.exe` and process the UTF-16 LE encoded output of it. See Microsoft documentation for [Win32_OperatingSystem class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) and [Win32_VideoController class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller).

Comment: @EadwineYoun For C++ code examples using these two WMI classes look on the Stack Overflow search results [\[c++\] Win32_OperatingSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+Win32_OperatingSystem) and [\[c++\] Win32_VideoController](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+Win32_VideoController). Both searches can be limited even more on using additionally `class` as word to find in a question or answer.

Comment: @Mofi Oh, so you mean I can use all these functions without accessing the custom batch files?

Comment: [popen(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Comment: @EadwineYoun Yes, you can write your C++ application with using these classes in Windows libraries. There is no need to run `wmic.exe` directly as process from within your C++ application or indirectly via a command process and a batch file. `wmic.exe` uses also just Windows libraries to get the data and output them. See also [WMI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-reference) linking to __COM API for WMI__ linking to [Creating a WMI Application Using C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/creating-a-wmi-application-using-c-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect output when using system():

```
#include <cstdio>   // std::remove(const char*)
#include <cstdlib>  // std::system(const char*)
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
  std::string foo_bat = "foo.bat";
  std::string foo_out = "foo.out";

  // Write the batch file
  {
    std::ofstream f( foo_bat );
    f << R"z(
      @echo off
      wmic os get caption /value
      wmic path win32_videocontroller get description /value
    )z";
  }

  // Execute the batch file, redirecting output using the current (narrow) code page
  if (!!std::system( (foo_bat + " | find /v \"\" > " + foo_out + " 2> NUL").c_str() ))
  {
    // (Clean up and complain)
    std::remove( foo_bat.c_str() );
    std::remove( foo_out.c_str() );
    std::cout << "fooey!\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Read the redirected output file
  std::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> env;
  {
    std::ifstream f( foo_out );
    std::string s;
    while (getline( f >> std::ws, s ))
    {
      auto n = s.find( '=' );
      if (n != s.npos)
        env[ s.substr( 0, n ) ] = s.substr( n+1 );
    }
  }

  // Clean up
  std::remove( foo_bat.c_str() );
  std::remove( foo_out.c_str() );

  // Show the user what we got
  for (auto p : env)
    std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

[WMIC is a problematic program when it comes to controlling the output code page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310573/wmic-command-in-batch-outputting-non-utf-8-text-files), hence the weird pipe trick we use with `system()`.

But, after all that, [you should use the WMI API directly to get this kind of information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer).

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I have now other problem with it. Looks like your code returns only one videocard. I have NVIDIA GeForce and Intel HD Graphics on my laptop and it couts only the Intel one.

Comment: @EadwineYoun The code that returns the (primary) video card is _yours_, from your question. How to get a list of all attached video cards in C or C++ would be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

A possible, though admittedly not ideal solution would be to have the batch file write it's output to a .txt file and then read in that file into your program. Look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484151/redirecting-output-from-within-batch-file) to see how to do this.